# Picasso not loading images Android (with Parse)

Tags: android, image, parse-platform, picasso

Images are not loading. It was working when I used a ParseQueryAdapter but I thought this would make the listview more smooth. Previously I tried the commented out code as well but that wasn't irking either. Here is my code for the BaseAdapter using Picasso:

```
public class PicassoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context myContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ParseFile p;
    String url;
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<ParseFile> mpl;

    static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView i;
    }

    public PicassoAdapter(Context c,List<ParseFile> pl){
        this.myContext = c;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.myContext);
        this.mpl = pl;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.mpl.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.mpl.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        p = (ParseFile)getItem(position);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v == null){
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_item3, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.i = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.snyp_image_new);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }



        /*ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Photo");
        query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objs, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(objs!=null){
                    for(int i = 0; i < objs.size();i++){
                        p = objs.get(i).getParseFile("photo");
                        url = p.getUrl();
                        s.add(url);

                    }
                }

            }

        });

        for(int x = 0;x<s.size();x++){
            Picasso.with(myContext).load(s.get(x)).into(viewHolder.i);
        }
        */
        Picasso.with(myContext).load(p.getUrl()).into(viewHolder.i);


        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but the `getUrl()` method on `ParseFile` returns a local URL on your filesystem. In your method here you only have a reference to a ParseFile object, but this hasn't yet been downloaded to your device and thus getUrl() doesn't point to a meaningful file.

If you use `p.loadInBackground()` you would be able to access the file's URL within that method's callback, but this might not be the best solution.

Comment: any updates on that? have you found a better solution?